# Add the ability to further refine search results?

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, search

While the similar questions presented when creating your own is helpful, I generally find search to be better at identifying these possible duplicates.

Therefore, in order to ease searching, I propose adding a method to filter results post-search by using "Related tags".

I know you can include the desired game or topic in the search query, but it is more intuitive to start with a large list of results and filter them down after.

Comment: That's one hell of an edit @nick, now I kind of understand.

Comment: [status-bydesign] as per @Nick's answer - you can do exactly what you want by just appending to your previous query.

Answer (score 4):

> *I'm treating this somewhat like a [support](/questions/tagged/support) question as with the current system I think you can largely do what you're asking, though it's a manual process.  Let me know what you think.*

After a [search](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search), for example "[stealth killing](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=stealth+killing&submit=search)", that query remains in the search box which you can continue to tweak as desired<sup>‡</sup>, say to "[stealth killing [deus-ex-human-revolution]](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=stealth+killing+%5Bdeus-ex-human-revolution%5D&submit=search)"

Note that if you add a search term in square brackets `[]`, it will be interpreted as a tag, even if it isn't popular enough to automatically be so.  Check out the [search page](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search) for more methods to improve your queries.

<sup>‡If you tweak too fast; more than 6 searches in 1 minute, you get rate limited.</sup>

Comment: I didnt quite notice that the initial query was left in the search box, though its still more intuitive to have the related tags available. I see it is just not relevant.